# How trustworthy are the confidence intervals for lmer objects through effects package?

Tags: r, mixed-model, confidence-interval, effects, lme4-nlme

[`Effects` package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/effects/index.html) provides a very fast and convenient way for [plotting linear mixed effect model results](http://www.r-bloggers.com/plotting-mixed-effects-model-results-with-effects-package/) obtained through [`lme4` package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lme4/index.html). The `effect` function calculates confidence intervals (CIs) very quickly, but how [trustworthy](http://glmm.wikidot.com/faq) are these confidence intervals?

For example:

```
library(lme4)
library(effects)
library(ggplot)

data(Pastes)

fm1  <- lmer(strength ~ batch + (1 | cask), Pastes)
effs <- as.data.frame(effect(c("batch"), fm1))
ggplot(effs, aes(x = batch, y = fit, ymin = lower, ymax = upper)) + 
  geom_rect(xmax = Inf, xmin = -Inf, ymin = effs[effs$batch == "A", "lower"],
        ymax = effs[effs$batch == "A", "upper"], alpha = 0.5, fill = "grey") +
  geom_errorbar(width = 0.2) + geom_point() + theme_bw()
```

[image]

According to CIs calculated using `effects` package, batch "E" does not overlap with batch "A".

If I try the same using `confint.merMod` function and the default method:

```
a <- fixef(fm1)
b <- confint(fm1)
# Computing profile confidence intervals ...
# There were 26 warnings (use warnings() to see them)

b <- data.frame(b)
b <- b[-1:-2,]

b1 <- b[[1]]
b2 <- b[[2]]

dt <- data.frame(fit   = c(a[1],  a[1] + a[2:length(a)]), 
                 lower = c(b1[1],  b1[1] + b1[2:length(b1)]), 
                 upper = c(b2[1],  b2[1] + b2[2:length(b2)]) )
dt$batch <- LETTERS[1:nrow(dt)]

ggplot(dt, aes(x = batch, y = fit, ymin = lower, ymax = upper)) +
  geom_rect(xmax = Inf, xmin = -Inf, ymin = dt[dt$batch == "A", "lower"], 
        ymax = dt[dt$batch == "A", "upper"], alpha = 0.5, fill = "grey") + 
  geom_errorbar(width = 0.2) + geom_point() + theme_bw()
```

[image]

I see that all of the CIs overlap. I also get warnings indicating that the function failed to calculate trustworthy CIs. This example, and my actual dataset, makes me to suspect that `effects` package takes shortcuts in CI calculation that might not entirely be approved by statisticians. **How trustworthy are the CIs returned by `effect` function from `effects` package for `lmer` objects?**

What have I tried: Looking into the source code, I noticed that `effect` function relies on `Effect.merMod` function, which in turn directs to `Effect.mer` function, which looks like this:

```
effects:::Effect.mer
function (focal.predictors, mod, ...) 
{
    result <- Effect(focal.predictors, mer.to.glm(mod), ...)
    result$formula <- as.formula(formula(mod))
    result
}
<environment: namespace:effects>
```

`mer.to.glm` function seems to calculate Variance-Covariate Matrix from the `lmer`object:

```
effects:::mer.to.glm

function (mod) 
{
...
mod2$vcov <- as.matrix(vcov(mod))
...
mod2
}
```

This, in turn, is probably used in `Effect.default` function to calculate CIs (I might have misunderstood this part):

```
effects:::Effect.default
...
     z <- qnorm(1 - (1 - confidence.level)/2)
        V <- vcov.(mod)
        eff.vcov <- mod.matrix %*% V %*% t(mod.matrix)
        rownames(eff.vcov) <- colnames(eff.vcov) <- NULL
        var <- diag(eff.vcov)
        result$vcov <- eff.vcov
        result$se <- sqrt(var)
        result$lower <- effect - z * result$se
        result$upper <- effect + z * result$se
...
```

I do not know enough about LMMs to judge whether this is a right approach, but considering the discussion around confidence interval calculation for LMMs, this approach appears suspiciously simple.

Comment: When you have long lines of code, I would greatly appreciate it if you break them into multiple lines so we don't have to scroll to see it all.

Comment: @rvl The code should be more readable now.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

All of the results are essentially the same (**for this particular example**).  Some theoretical differences are:

- as @rvl points out, your reconstruction of CIs without taking account of covariance among parameters is just wrong (sorry)
- confidence intervals for parameters can be based on Wald confidence intervals (assuming a quadratic log-likelihood surface): `lsmeans`, `effects`, `confint(.,method="Wald")`; except for `lsmeans`, these methods ignore finite-size effects ("degrees of freedom"), but in this case it barely makes any difference (`df=40` is practically indistinguishable from infinite `df`)
- ... or on *profile confidence intervals* (the default method; ignores finite-size effects but allows for non-quadratic surfaces)
- ... or on *parametric bootstrapping* (the gold standard -- assumes the model is correct [responses are Normal, random effects are Normally distributed, data are conditionally independent, etc.], but otherwise makes few assumptions)

I think all of these approaches are *reasonable* (some are more approximate than others), but in this case it barely makes any difference which one you use.  If you're concerned, try out several contrasting methods on your data, or on simulated data that resemble your own, and see what happens ...

(PS: I wouldn't put too much weight on the fact that the confidence intervals of `A` and `E` don't overlap.  You'd have to do a proper pairwise comparison procedure to make reliable inferences about the differences between this *particular* pair of estimates ...)

95% CIs:

[image]

Comparison code:

```
library(lme4)
fm2 <- lmer(strength ~ batch - 1 + (1 | cask), Pastes)
c0 <- confint(fm2,method="Wald")
c1 <- confint(fm2)
c2 <- confint(fm2,method="boot")
library(effects)
library(lsmeans)
c3 <- with(effect("batch",fm2),cbind(lower,upper))
c4 <- with(summary(lsmeans(fm2,spec="batch")),cbind(lower.CL,upper.CL))
tmpf <- function(method,val) {
    data.frame(method=method,
               v=LETTERS[1:10],
               setNames(as.data.frame(tail(val,10)),
                        c("lwr","upr")))
}
library(ggplot2); theme_set(theme_bw())
allCI <- rbind(tmpf("lme4_wald",c0),
      tmpf("lme4_prof",c1),
      tmpf("lme4_boot",c2),
      tmpf("effects",c3),
               tmpf("lsmeans",c4))
ggplot(allCI,aes(v,ymin=lwr,ymax=upr,colour=method))+
    geom_linerange(position=position_dodge(width=0.8))

ggsave("pastes_confint.png",width=10)
```

Comment: I accept this answer as it is right to the point and gives a nice comparison between different methods. However, check out rlv's excellent answer for more information.

Comment: Thank you for excellent and very helpful answer. Do I understand correctly that one cannot use CIs to compare groups/batches, but it is possible to compare effects. Say that I had two treatments, several individuals and several measurements within individuals. I would use individuals as random effect as each of them would contain x measurements. Then I wanted to know whether these two treatments resulted to a different response. Could I use `effects` package and CI overlap in this case?

Comment: This is a more general question which is relevant to any standard model-based approach. Might be worth a separate question. (1) In general the way one answers questions about differences between treatments is to set up the model so that the difference between the focal treatments is a *contrast* (i.e., an estimated parameter) in the model, and then to calculate a p-value or check whether the confidence intervals at a particular alpha-level include zero. (continued)

Comment: (2) overlapping CIs is at best a conservative, and approximate, criterion for differences between parameters (there are several published papers on this topic).  (3) There's a separate/orthogonal issue with pairwise comparisons, which is that one has to control appropriately for multiplicity and non-independence of the comparisons (this *can* be done, e.g. by the methods in the `multcomp` package, but it requires at least a little bit of care)

Comment: Is it better to use lmertest, lsmeans or mertools?

Comment: For what?  You might want to ask a new question.

Comment: For example for the OP problem. Which one (lmertest or mertools) is more accurate, makes fewer assumptions or has some advantage or is usable in a broader set of problems.

Answer (score 21):

It looks like what you have done in the second method is to have computed confidence intervals for the regression coefficients, then transformed those to obtain CIs for the predictions. This ignores the covariances between the regression coefficients.

Try fitting the model without an intercept, so that the `batch` effects will actually be the predictions, and `confint` will return the intervals you need.

### Addendum 1

I did exactly what I suggested above:

```
> fm2 <- lmer(strength ~ batch - 1 + (1 | cask), Pastes)
> confint(fm2)
Computing profile confidence intervals ...
           2.5 %    97.5 %
.sig01  0.000000  1.637468
.sigma  2.086385  3.007380
batchA 60.234772 64.298581
batchB 57.268105 61.331915
batchC 60.018105 64.081915
batchD 57.668105 61.731915
batchE 53.868105 57.931915
batchF 59.001439 63.065248
batchG 57.868105 61.931915
batchH 61.084772 65.148581
batchI 56.651439 60.715248
batchJ 56.551439 60.615248
```

These intervals seem to jibe with the results from `effects`.

### Addendum 2

Another alternative is the **lsmeans** package. It obtains degrees of freedom and an adjusted covariance matrix from the **pbkrtest** package.

```
> library("lsmeans")
> lsmeans(fm1, "batch")
Loading required namespace: pbkrtest
 batch   lsmean       SE    df lower.CL upper.CL
 A     62.26667 1.125709 40.45 59.99232 64.54101
 B     59.30000 1.125709 40.45 57.02565 61.57435
 C     62.05000 1.125709 40.45 59.77565 64.32435
 D     59.70000 1.125709 40.45 57.42565 61.97435
 E     55.90000 1.125709 40.45 53.62565 58.17435
 F     61.03333 1.125709 40.45 58.75899 63.30768
 G     59.90000 1.125709 40.45 57.62565 62.17435
 H     63.11667 1.125709 40.45 60.84232 65.39101
 I     58.68333 1.125709 40.45 56.40899 60.95768
 J     58.58333 1.125709 40.45 56.30899 60.85768

Confidence level used: 0.95
```

These are even more in line with the `effect` results: the standard errors are identical, but `effect` uses different d.f. The `confint` results in Addendum 1 are even *narrower* than the asymptotic ones based on using $\pm1.96\times\mbox{se}$. So now I think those are *not* very trustworthy.

Results from `effect` and `lsmeans` are similar, but with an unbalanced multi-factor situation, `lsmeans` by default averages over unused factors with equal weights, whereas `effect` weights by the observed frequencies (available as an option in `lsmeans`).

Comment: Thank you for this solution. Intervals are now more similar, although not exactly the same. Your answer still does not answer the question whether CIs from `effects` package can be trusted for `lmer` objects. I am considering using the results in a publication and want to be sure that CIs are calculated using an approved method for LMMs.

Comment: Would you please tell : in your Addendum 1 the first two parameters `.sig01` and `.sigma` produces by `confint` , are those confidence interval for **variance** ? or confidence interval of  **standard deviation**  ?

Comment: They are CIs for whatever parameters are labeled that way in the model. You should look at the documentation for `lmer` for a definitive answer. However, people usually use notations like `sigma` to refer to standard deviations, and `sigma.square` or `sigma^2` to refer to variances.

Comment: Is it better to use lmertest, lsmeans or mertools?