# Calculating confidence intervals of marginal means in linear mixed models

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, glmm, effects

I'm using different R packages (`effects`, `ggeffects`, `emmeans`, `lmer`) to calculate confidence intervals of marginal means in a linear mixed model. My problem is that the `effects` package produces smaller CIs compared to other methods. Here is an example:

```
library(effects)
library(ggeffects)
library(emmeans)
library(lmerTest)
library(ggplot2)

ham$Age_scale <- scale(ham$Age)

# fit model without the intercept
fit <- lmer(Informed.liking ~ -1 + Product + Age_scale +
   (1|Consumer/Product), data=ham)
```

Model summary:

```
Random effects:
 Groups           Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 Product:Consumer (Intercept) 3.1464   1.7738  
 Consumer         (Intercept) 0.3908   0.6252  
 Residual                     1.6991   1.3035  
Number of obs: 648, groups:  Product:Consumer, 324; Consumer, 81

Fixed effects:
           Estimate Std. Error        df t value Pr(>|t|)    
Product1  5.809e+00  2.327e-01 3.110e+02  24.960   <2e-16 ***
Product2  5.105e+00  2.327e-01 3.110e+02  21.936   <2e-16 ***
Product3  6.093e+00  2.327e-01 3.110e+02  26.180   <2e-16 ***
Product4  5.926e+00  2.327e-01 3.110e+02  25.464   <2e-16 ***
Age_scale 9.621e-03  1.311e-01 7.900e+01   0.073    0.942
```

Then, I used different methods to calculate the CIs for the marginal means for `Product`:

```
term = 'Product'

## ggpredict
c0 <- as.data.frame(ggpredict(fit, terms = term))
c0 <- c0[,4:5]

## confint.merMod
c1 <- confint(fit, method='profile')
c1 <- c1[4:7,]

## confint.merMod
c2 <- confint(fit,method='Wald')
c2 <- c2[4:7,]

## confint.merMod
c3 <- confint(fit,method='boot')
c3 <- c3[4:7,]

## effect
c4 <- with(effect(term,fit),cbind(lower,upper))

## emmeans,'kenward-roger'
c5 <- with(summary(emmeans(fit,spec=term)),cbind(lower.CL,upper.CL))
```

I put all the CIs together:

```
tmpf <- function(method,val) {
    data.frame(method=method,
               v=LETTERS[1:4],
               setNames(as.data.frame(tail(val,4)),
                        c("lwr","upr")))
}

allCI <- rbind(tmpf("ggpredict",c0),
               tmpf('profile',c1),
               tmpf('wald',c2),
               tmpf('boot',c3),
               tmpf("effects",c4),
               tmpf("emmeans",c5))

ggplot(allCI,aes(v,ymin=lwr,ymax=upr,colour=method))+
    geom_linerange(position=position_dodge(width=0.8),size=1) + theme_bw()
```

[image: Confidence Intervals for Marginal Means]

The confidence intervals produced by the `effects` package are substantially smaller than others. I noticed someone asked [a similar question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/117641/how-trustworthy-are-the-confidence-intervals-for-lmer-objects-through-effects-pa) before, but its answers showed that CIs produced by`effects` are very similar to others. I wonder what's going on here. Did I miss something?

UPDATE: @Daniel ran the exact same code and found no deviation for the **effects** package. **ggeffect()** and **ggemmeans()** from version 0.8.0 of the **ggeffects** package also produced very similar CIs.

However, I still got smaller CIs for **effects** (version 4.0.1) and **ggeffects** (version 0.7.0), at .95 confidence level.

```
## effect
eff = effect(term,fit)
c4 <- with(eff,cbind(lower,upper))

## emmeans,'kenward-roger'
c5 <- with(summary(emmeans(fit,spec=term)),cbind(lower.CL,upper.CL))

## ggeffect
c6 <- ggeffect(fit, terms = term)
c6 <- c6[,4:5]

packageVersion('ggeffects')
‘0.7.0’
packageVersion('effects')
‘4.0.1’
eff$confidence.level
0.95
```

[image]

After upgrading to the latest versions, however, all methods produced similar CIs.

```
packageVersion('ggeffects')
‘0.8.0’
packageVersion('effects')
‘4.1.0’

## effect
eff = effect(term,fit)
c4 <- with(eff,cbind(lower,upper))

## emmeans,'kenward-roger'
c5 <- with(summary(emmeans(fit,spec=term)),cbind(lower.CL,upper.CL))

## ggeffect
c6 <- ggeffect(fit, terms = term)
c6 <- c6[,4:5]

## ggemmeans (only the 0.8.0 version supports this)
c7 <- ggemmeans(fit, terms = term)
c7 <- c7[,4:5]
```

[image]

Comment: Good to know where this error comes from. The smaller CI for ggeffects 0.7.0 in your example seem plausible (and would also have occured with ggeffects 0.8.0), because the `ggeffect()` function simply wraps `effect()` - and if the source of this "bug" was the older version 4.0.1 of the effect-package, `ggeffect()` will also have this "bug".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have just checked your example (using the just released version 0.8.0 of **ggeffects**), however, instead of using `effect()` or `emmeans()` directly, I use the functions from **ggeffects**, which actually wrap around these functions (`ggeffect()` and `ggemmeans()`).

```
## effect
c4 <- ggeffect(fit, terms = term)
c4 <- c4[,4:5]

## emmeans,'kenward-roger'
c5 <- ggemmeans(fit, terms = term)
c5 <- c5[,4:5]
```

Here, the CI's are similar.

[image]

Also, after exactly running your examples, the plot is identical, with no deviation for **effects**.

```
## effect
c4 <- with(effect(term,fit),cbind(lower,upper))

## emmeans,'kenward-roger'
c5 <- with(summary(emmeans(fit,spec=term)),cbind(lower.CL,upper.CL))
```

[image]

Have you set some options for the **effects**-package that might change the ci-level?

It seems to me that all these methods produce *confidence intervals*, not *prediction intervals*. If you use `type = "re"` in `ggpredict()`, the intervals are much larger (except for this model, because the variance in the random effects is almost zero).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I found that updating the effects package from 4.0.1 to 4.1.0 resolved the problem.